# How to do some calculation in expect script?

Tags: tcl, expect

What I need to do is to set a variable at the beginning of an expect script to a value which depends on th size of a file. What I need to do is something like this:

```
set filesize `stat -c%s foo.bin`
set factor 42
set timeout $filesize / $factor
```

I already searched around for some tutorials, but searching the keywords 'expect' and 'calculation' are too common, so the search results do not face the unix binary /usr/bin/expect.

How to do some calculation in expect script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to call out to `stat`:

```
set filesize [file size foo.bin]
```

See https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm#M34

Answer (score 1):

Expect uses Tcl so you also need to learn [Tcl's manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/contents.htm).

To quickly help you out:

```
set filesize [exec stat -c%s foo.bin]
set factor 42
set timeout [expr {$filesize / $factor}]
```